# How to extract degree of freedom in R package rmgarch by dccroll()

Tags: r

I have a dataset containing returns of 3 assets. I want to forecast the VaR for the out-of-sample period. I use the package rmgarch and assume for a multi-t distribution. The codes I write as follows:

```
    spec <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(model = "sGARCH"), 
    distribution.model = "norm")
    spec_m_gar <- multispec(c(spec, spec, spec))
    spec_m_dcc <- dccspec(spec_m_gar, distribution = "mvt")
    roll_m_dcc <- dccroll(spec_m_dcc, X_SOFT, n.ahead = 1, 
    forecast.length = 2000, refit.every = 66, refit.window = "moving", 
    cluster = cluster)
```

Now I want to extract the degree of freedom of the multi-t distribution and I'm trying to use

```
    rshape(roll_m_dcc)
```

But I got this error: Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = c("roll-1", "roll-2", "roll-3",  : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions

Also, I don't understand "dccspec" function very well. For the first specification of the "ugarchspec", what does "distribution.model" exactly mean since there is "distribution = "mvt" " in "dccspec" already.

Thank you very much for the help!!!

Comment: is there a `df.residual(roll_m_dcc)` for the package?

Comment: No I don't think so. It returns an error: Error: $ operator not defined for this S4 class.